# How to solve dyld: Symbol not found - Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib ( _fdopendir$INODE64 )

Tags: python, macos, gcc, conda

I searched for it, could not find much references.
I guess:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Users/gg4u/Sites/miniconda3/envs/meteo/bin/python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

is an error related to how some libraries are compiled.

I am running a mac os 10.9.5.

I got this error after having installed fbprophet on a conda environment.

NOTE - First installation was successful.

This error first appeared when importing the fbprophet library in python.

I tried to uninstall, reinstall again, but this time error manifested also at installation.

It seems conda environment got corrupted.

Tried to look for earlier versions of fbprophet, could not find but the 0.5 :
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fbprophet

Please advise what this error could be and how to solve it.

Maybe could I manually linked it ? Could I download an upgraded version of /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib ?

Answer (score 0):

`fdopendir` is not available on macOS 10.9.5; it's available from macOS 10.10.

Per `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/dirent.h`:

```
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_10, __IPHONE_8_0)
DIR *fdopendir(int) __DARWIN_ALIAS_I(fdopendir);
```

It looks like something is built incorrectly if it should work on your 10.9.5 installation.  The compiler and linker need `-mmacosx-version-min=10.9`.  Although I have seen Python itself fail to honour this when building it due its flawed feature detection (does a compile test without attempting linking).  We actually had to build Python against the MacOSX.sdk from an older version of Xcode or on the target platform itself to resolve that.

Answer (score -1):

### Possible Cause: Channel Mixing

Missing symbols is a typical outcome of improper channel mixing. Conda Forge (**conda-forge**) and Anaconda (**defaults**) channels use different build stacks and this can lead to references to symbols that don't translate across channels. Since you are using Conda Forge to source `fbprophet`, you should follow [Conda Forge's recommended configuration](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels), which sets `channel_priority: strict` and places **conda-forge** channel before **defaults**.

After making these changes, it may be sufficient to run `conda update --all` in the environment (though this may pull newer versions than you want). Otherwise, I would probably dump the environment with `conda env export --no-builds`, then recreate after making sure the channel priority is correct in the YAML.

Comment: tks @merv I don't know why your answer was downvoted, either if your answer solve the question: next time I'll meet this error, I try to select channels differently giving priority to conda-forge with `channel_priority: strict`. However, so far I did not have luck by manually selecting sources: as an example, I got this issues when installing computer vision libraries (open-cv) and mixing sources from `pip`, `conda` or `conda-forge`. If error happens, I got to destroy the environment and recreated it. I think it has to do with order to install packages and my local `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`

Comment: @user305883 thanks for replying. Could you perhaps post the YAML for the environment? I.e., the output of `conda env export > env.yaml`? If short, add it to the question; if long, [make a Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or something similar.

Comment: ok! I posted three yaml from different envs https://gist.github.com/gg4u/73189d3fe8f476948e96b1d8bc9e2dc0